# I want to find a natural faithful action with the wreath product.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets. Let $G\leq \operatorname{Sym}(A)$ and $H\leq\operatorname{Sym}(B)$. Can any one find a faithful action of the wreath product $G\wr H$ on $A\times B$?
 If there is no such action, you can have some assumptions. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean on $A \times B$ don't you, in which case there is such an action.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wonder your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Let $$\left((g_b)_{b\in B},h\right)\in G\wr H$$ Define $$\left((g_b)_{b\in B},h\right)(a,b')=\left(g_{h(b')}(a),h(b')\right)$$
Check that this is a faithful action, which is called the imprimitive action. Here you can find more on [Canonical Actions of Wreath Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product#Canonical_Actions_of_Wreath_Products).

Comment: Are you sure the action? Because I didn't show that it is an action.

Comment: Why is it called Canonical, Dennis?

Comment: I'm not really sure why. Perhaps it is because those are the most natural actions of a wreath product one can define. Anyway, it is not my terminology :-)